# SWRevealViewcontroller not working with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I have implemented `SWRevealViewcontroller` for drawer in my app, but in navigation bar right bar button can't be displayed in `iOS 7.1` but gesture works,

Comment: Can you share some code, How you are using SWRevealViewcontroller?

Comment: try to change the text color and keep an image for bar button programatically

Comment: I haven't ever experience with storyBoard but put relevant code here so we can help you..

Comment: thanks for ipatel can u share your code

Comment: @pankaj for which code ?

Comment: @ipatel any sample drawer with child view controller

Answer (score 2):

Actualy it works, I m using it my self, check this tutorial :

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: i can not use slide menu plz suggest another way to use slide menu

Comment: did you tried to follow the steps on the tutorial ? try to download the code sample and run it

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController).

`MMDrawerController` is a side drawer navigation container view controller designed to support the growing number of applications that leverage the side drawer paradigm. This library is designed to exclusively support side drawer navigation in a light-weight, focused approach while exposing the ability to provide custom animations for presenting and dismissing the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

To display the right bar button you will have to set the rightBarButtonItem in the navigationItem.Like this:

```
SWRevealViewController *reveal = [self revealViewController];

UIBarButtonItem *revealButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:reveal action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = revealButton;
```

By this you will get the right bar button and from it's @selector method you will be able to drag out the right menu.

Don't forget to import SWRevealViewController.
It works for me and I am using iOS 7.1. Hope it works for you.